# How to center an image inside a circle

Tags: html, css

Can someone help and tell me how I can center an image inside the circle as show in the image below.

[image]

Before writing this post I spend some time looking for an answer but I could not find out how.

Here is the only code i have, this is HTML:

```
<div class="service">
    <div class="circle">      
      <!-- <img src="/assets/images/engineering.png" alt="image mécanisme"> -->
      </div>
     <h2>Automatiser votre<br>funnel d'acquisition</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Now add the css too, so that we can know where the issue begins

Comment: How about putting the image is as a background-image to the element positioned center and size contain for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HTML, position the image inside the parent div (which is the circle div).

In the parent div (with class circle), using CSS add

```
.circle { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center}
```

This should add the image into the circle div.

Please mark this as correct if it's helpful.